# Capitalize in Solaris Shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, solaris

Hi I want to capitalize a variable in Solaris OS.

From HELLO_WORLD to Hello_World

Or also HELLO to Hello

Please help, this is Solaris OS:

Oracle Solaris 10 8/11 s10s_u10wos_17b SPARC Copyright (c) 1983, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved. Assembled 23 August 2011

Answer (score 1):

If you have Perl:

```
% echo HELLO_WORLD FOO bar | perl -pe '($_ = lc $_) =~ s/(\b|_)./\U$&/g'
Hello_World Foo Bar
```

`perl -pe` reads from standard input and prints each line after applying the Perl code given as an argument. `$_` is the current line. The `lc` function converts a string to lower case. The regular expression matches a word boundary or underscore followed by any character. The `s///` command replaces any matching substring by its uppercase equivalent. The trailing `g` causes the replacement to be performed as many times as possible on each line (by default it's done once).

If you don't have Perl (I don't know whether Solaris includes it by default), try this:

```
% echo HELLO_WORLD FOO bar | tr A-Z a-z | sed 's/\(_\|\<\)./\U&/g'
Hello_World Foo Bar
```

You could incorporate the upper-to-lower case mapping into the `sed` command using `y///`, but unlike `tr` it doesn't appear to accept ranges:

```
% echo HELLO_WORLD FOO bar | tr A-Z a-z | sed 'y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/;s/\(_\|\<\)./\U&/g'
Hello_World Foo Bar
```